# how to auto load FEH and play jpg from usb flash drive?

Tags: slideshow

I'm using Ubuntu Mate for the odroid c2.
In Control Center/Startup Applications, I added my own `/home/odroid/feh.sh
feh.sh` has:

```
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
feh --quiet --fullscreen --borderless --hide-pointer --randomize --slideshow-delay 30 /media/usb/
```

that didnt work. please help.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

i dont know why it matters, but adding sleep 15 works!
so the final code in `feh.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 15
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
feh --quiet --fullscreen --borderless --hide-pointer --randomize --slideshow-delay 30 /media/usb/
```

Comment: Interesting :-) I guess that something important was not found directly after log in. Maybe the USB drive needed time to be mounted. *I'm glad that you found a working solution.* - Anyway, I was interested, so I made and tested a desktop file (with Ubuntu MATE live in a Toshiba laptop).

Answer (score 0):

### General

`feh` wants a wild-card character in the path (and it will search subdirectories too), or the option `--recursive` So I suggest that you try

```
feh --quiet --fullscreen --borderless --hide-pointer --randomize --slideshow-delay 30 /media/usb/*
```

or

```
feh --quiet --fullscreen --borderless --hide-pointer --randomize --slideshow-delay 30 --recursive /media/usb/
```

---

I use the two aliases

```
alias feha='feh -r -F -V -d -Z'

alias fehs='feh -r -F -V -d -Z -z -D 5'
```

### Details of a working desktop file in 'autostart'

I tested in Ubuntu MATE and added details of a working desktop file in 'autostart'.

The following desktop file `feh-slideshow.desktop` works in Ubuntu MATE Bionic (to be released soon as 18.04 LTS).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Name=feh-slideshow
Comment=perform a slideshow
Exec=feh --quiet --fullscreen --borderless --hide-pointer --randomize --slideshow-delay 30 --recursive /media/usb/
Icon=/usr/share/icons/mate/scalable/apps/mate.svg
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

- I tested it 'manually' when located on the Desktop.
- It works automatically at log in, when located in `~/.config/autostart`
- You may want to point to another directory (instead of `/media/usb/`).
- You may want/need another icon in a different version of Ubuntu MATE.

The following screenshot illustrates a working system, where you can logout via 'End the current session' log out and log in which starts the slideshow.

[image]

Comment: this didnt work unfortunately. very strange i can run in terminal:  bash feh.sh.     but it refuses to automatically run by itself after reboot

Comment: It should work, if you run a script with only one line, the one with `feh`. Why are you running the other lines? Are you using a desktop file 'slideshow.desktop` ? In that case, please edit your original question to show that desktop file.

Comment: i just edited the feh.sh file down to 1 line. i removed all the other xset as you suggested.

i added /home/odroid/feh.sh to Autostart application. then i see a file was created automatically in home/odroid/.config/autostart/feh.sh.desktop.  i reboot and still nothing works. feh did not auto start

Comment: @PhillyHot, it works for me according to the edited answer. I use only a desktop file (no shellscript).